# style.hide_index() adds multiple zeros after decimal

Tags: python, pandas

Here was what I'm working on

```
df_top_50= df[['Rank', 'Player', 'Position', 'Age', 'Nationality', 'Club Left', 'Club Joined', 'Transfer Fee (EUR)']]
```

It returned

```
   Rank Player              Position    Age Nationality Club Left       Club Joined        Transfer Fee (EUR)
1   1   Antony              Forward     22  Netherlands Ajax Amsterdam  Manchester United   95.00
2   2   Wesley Fofana       Defender    21  England     Leicester City  Chelsea FC          80.40
3   3   Aurélien Tchouameni Midfielder  22  Monaco      AS Monaco       Real Madrid         80.00
```

I wanna get rid of the index column, so I add `style.hide_index()`:

```
df_top_50= df[['Rank', 'Player', 'Position', 'Age', 'Nationality', 'Club Left', 'Club Joined', 'Transfer Fee (EUR)']].style.hide_index()
```

I got what I want, but the values in transfer fee column suddenly added 0s after decimal:

```
Rank    Player              Position   Age  Nationality Club Left       Club Joined       Transfer Fee (EUR)
1       Antony              Forward    22   Netherlands Ajax Amsterdam  Manchester United 95.000000
2       Wesley Fofana       Defender   21   England     Leicester City  Chelsea FC        80.400000
3       Aurélien Tchouameni Midfielder 22   Monaco      AS Monaco       Real Madrid       80.000000
```

Is there any way to put it back, like in the first dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

If OP's goal is to round the values in the column `Transfer Fee (EUR)`, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) as

```
df = df.round({'Transfer Fee (EUR)': 1})
```

Then the values of that column will be

```
0    95.0
1    80.4
2    80.0
```

Alternatively, if OP wants to specify the exact number of decimal places, assuming one wants that number to be `2`, then one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as follows

```
df['Transfer Fee (EUR)'] = df['Transfer Fee (EUR)'].apply('{0:.2f}'.format)
```

Then the values of that column will be

```
0    95.00
1    80.40
2    80.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [**`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index.html) is deprecated, use [**`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide) instead.

> **Deprecated since version 1.4.0**: This method should be replaced by
> hide(axis="index", **kwargs)

Try this :

```
df.style.format({'Transfer Fee (EUR)': "{:.2f}"}).hide()
```

##### # Ouput :

[image]